# Easily disable log4j for applet?

Tags: java, logging, applet, log4j, warnings

I am building Java Desktop and Java Applet from the same code. Log4j is in use so almost every class in desktop version (which is original) has line like

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EachClassName.class);
```

Because Applet is not supposed to perform any io operations I had to exclude this configuration code:

```
InputStream is = Log4jConfigurator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
properties.load(is);
is.close();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);
```

But now I get warnings because `getLogger` is still in place

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.game.client.Client).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

What would be the most elegant solution to avoid this warnings and use logger only in desktop version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "Applet App" try to configure log4j programmatically:

1. turn off logging

   `LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);`
2. Add NullAppender (if setting Level.OFF is not enough)

   `LogManager.getRootLogger().addAppender(new NullAppender())`

Comment: I have edited from Logger to LogManager and it works, thanks!